# Problem with negative lookahead operator in a regex

Tags: regex

I have a string `==a==123==b==456==c==879` and I would like to get the letters and the numbers.

I try this with the expr `==(.*?)==(.*?)`.

This gives me:

```
 Match 1
    1.  a
    2.   
    Match 2
    1.  b
    2.   
    Match 3
    1.  c
    2.
```

... but the numbers are missing. How can I get them?

I want to get this:
This gives me:

```
Match 1
1.  a
2.  123
Match 2
1.  b
2.  456
Match 3
1.  c
2.  789
```

I believe I have to use a negative lookahead operator, but I can't figure out, how it works in this case.

(I separated letters and numbers for this example only. In real usage, I can separate by `==` only.)

Comment: Use `==([^=]*)==([^=]*)`

Comment: I can't use [^=], since inside the part with the numbers, single `=` can occur. I have to use two `=`.

Comment: So, you need not get *letters and numbers*, but any string up to the `==`. Use `==(.*?)==(.*?)(?===|$)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/HaCpCj/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may tell the regex to match up to `==` or end of string using

```
==(.*?)==(.*?)(?===|$)
==([\s\S]*?)==([\s\S]*?)(?===|$) # To also match line breaks in between ==
(?s)==(.*?)==(.*?)(?===|$)       # Also matches line breaks in between == in PHP and many other flavors but Ruby
(?m)==(.*?)==(.*?)(?===|\Z)      # To also match line breaks in between == in Ruby
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HaCpCj/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%3D%3D(.*%3F)%3D%3D(.*%3F)(%3F%3D%3D%3D%7C%24)):

[image]

**Details**

- `==` - a string of two `=` chars
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `==(.*?)` - `==` and Group 2 matching any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?===|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires `==` or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Yes, this works, thank you! But it does not work with linebreaks it it, even if I add the `m` option: https://rubular.com/r/RJNv6InoOdxFvD ()

Comment: @NilsWeg If it is for the Onigmo/Oniguruma, use `\z` instead of `$` (`$` is always the end of a line in Ruby). See [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/i3aGLTLqiYSwJv). It may require more tweaking for other environments.

Comment: It's not for Onigmo/Oniguruma. The `$` works fine for me. But `.*` does not match line breaks, like shown in the https://rubular.com/r/RJNv6InoOdxFvD link.

Comment: @NilsWeg Why are you testing a regex that is not going to be processed with Onigmo/Oniguruma in an Onigmo/Oniguruma regex tester??? Where are you going to use it? *The `$` works fine for me* - NO, in different regex engines, `$` matches different stuff.

Comment: I want to use it in PHP and there it does not work like shown in the given link.

Comment: @NilsWeg Of course, PHP uses PCRE/PCRE2, not Onigmo. And you must use `s` modifier in PCRE to make `.` match line break chars. Use `preg_match_all('~==(.*?)==(.*?)(?===|$)~s', $s, $matches)`